# "My" versus "me" in this context?

Tags: word-choice

I see this a lot:

> I shall say, Daphne, that ***my*** going to Athens on Saturday need not disturb our tea schedule one bit.

Versus what seems right to me:

> I shall say, Daphne, that ***me*** going to Athens on Saturday need not disturb our tea schedule one bit.

I'm *somewhat* sure that the former is actually the right one, but the latter always seems like the right one to me.

Can both be used? If seems weird to say "my going to Athens" as opposed to "me going to Athens", but the more I use "me" in this context, the less I sound like a native English speaker (which I'm not) and it bothers me.

Comment: In short (per the answer in the other question), both are acceptable. *My* is more formal and *me* is more informal. Of course, if you're really bothered by the choice, just write *my* ***trip*** *to Athens*.

Comment: Laurel’s link is a detailed and excellent answer to your question.